# Why would you write in Octal/Hexadecimal/Binary over Standard Notation?

Tags: php, binary, hex, octal

I was reading the [PHP documentation on Integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php), where it's specifies the different ways in which you can specify which notation to use. Here's a snippet of the doc for anyone interested.

```
<?php
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
$a = 0b11111111; // binary number (equivalent to 255 decimal)
?>
```

However, in PHP (and even some other programming languages where applicable), why would you ever choose to write in Octal, Hexadecimal, or Binary notation over Standard Notation (base 10). Doesn't this just make the numbers more difficult to read for other programmers?

Is there a physical boost in performance in any way by using one notation over another? Is it counter intuitive if you have to change the notation later to be readable by users? E.g. Record users age in Hexadecimal but display it in standard.

Comment: In some cases, working with a specific notation can be far more easier to read. For example, if you are working with RGB colors you will almost immediatly know that `0xFF0000` is the red color.

Comment: Defining constants for bitwise operations is also easier in hex: I don't have to look up the next value in the series after 0x10000, I know it's 0x20000.

Comment: Octal notation in particular is convenient for OS-related APIs (such as setting file access permissions). Other notations make sense for computational reasons too. -- Please elaborate why you assume a difficulty for other programmers? Why would you think syntactic options are performace-related?

Comment: @Cedroux That's an interesting point. Personally I've always opted for RGB colour values, and so never encountered the need to do that, however, upon that note, perhaps I should reconsider in certain circumstances.

Comment: @iainn Could you elaborate on this a little more? Surely I know the next value from the number 5 is 6?

Comment: @mario "Other notations make sense for computational reasons too" -- Such as? I would assume a difficulty for other programmers because base 10 is a standard by which most people recognise mathematics. It's generally a programmer specific tasks to learn Octal/Hexadecimal/Binary, and since it's not always required, some programmers may not recognise it/be familiar with it, and have to actively translate it over. I would think syntactic options are performance related because they often are; two functions are rarely if ever identical, they differ in small but potentially significant ways.

Comment: @cmprogram We're not talking about 5 and 6, we're talking about powers of two up to the billions. `0x1000000` > `0x2000000` is easier and clearer than `16777216` > `33554432`.

Comment: @iainn That's an excellent point, well explained.