# What is the point of writing integer in hexadecimal, octal and binary?

Tags: swift, floating-point, int, decimal, var

I am well aware that one is able to assign a value to an array or constant in Swift and have those value represented in different formats.

For Integer: One can declare in the formats of *decimal, binary, octal or hexadecimal*.

For Float or Double: One can declare in the formats of either *decimal or hexadecimal* and able to make use of the exponent too.

For instance:

```
var decInt = 17
var binInt = 0b10001
var octInt = 0o21
var hexInt = 0x11
```

All of the above variables gives the same result which is 17.

But what's the catch? Why bother using those other than decimal?

Comment: Same question (without answers, but with helpful comments) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199335/why-would-you-write-in-octal-hexadecimal-binary-over-standard-notation.

Comment: is php and swift responds the same way to those formats?

Comment: The format is partially different, but both languages have decimal/octal/hexadecimal/binary integer literals (as do some other languages). The answer to your *"why do we need that"* is the same, and independent of the language.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some notations that can be way easier to understand for people even if the result in the end is the same. You can for example think in cases like colour notation (hexadecimal) or file permission notation (octal).

Answer (score 0):

Code is best written in the most meaningful way.

Using the number format that best matches the domain of your program, is just one example.  You don't want to obscure domain specific details and want to minimize the mental effort for the reader of your code.

Two other examples:

- Do not simplify calculations.  For example: To convert a scaled integer value in 1/10000 arc minutes to a floating point in degrees, do not write the conversion factor as `600000.0`, but instead write `10000.0 * 60.0`.
- Chose a code structure that matches the nature of your data.  For example: If you have a function with two return values, determine if it's a symmetrical or asymmetrical situation. For a symmetrical situation always write a full `if (condition) { return A; } else { return B; }`.  It's a common mistake to write `if (condition) { return A; } return B;` (simply because 'it works').

Meaning matters!